# How to use a substitution variable in Toctree Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, substitution, restructuredtext, toctree

The problem consist to use a substitution variable `var_link` which is declared in `conf.py` file as follow :

`var_link = 'https://www.google.fr/'`

This variable is added into `rst_prolog` by

```
rst_prolog = f"""
.. |var_link| replace:: {var_link}
"""
```

And I need to use this link in my toctree index as :

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1

   Title <|var_link|>
```

When I try the above syntax, it gives me a warning :

> WARNING: toctree contains reference to nonexisting document '|var_link|'

Thanks for your helpful

Comment: You don't. The toctree doesn't accept any kind of reST construct as its item.

Answer (score -1):

Within conv.py

open("toctree.rst","w").write(f"""

.. toctree::
HOME file://{my_html_file}"
:hidden:

""")

Within rst file:

.. toctree::
.......

.. include:: toctree.rst

.. toctree::
.......

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add some explanation, not just code. Format the code properly (see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).